# How to refresh google authentication credentials in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am able to complete an auth flow to get a user's credentials -- however, I want to make sure that I can continue to use these credentials without them expiring. I am fully aware of rules for [token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration).

However, if periodically I want to 'refresh' the credentials I have of a user so I can make sure I can use them in perpetuity. Howe would I go about doing that?

I see Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) that says, "The client object will refresh the access token as needed"....so ok, does that mean I just need to initialize the client object as follows and like magic my credentials will always be up to date?

```
    # one way...credentials is a hash with an access and refresh token and a bunch of other key value pairs

    Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(credentials)

    # another way
    client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.new({web: credentials})

    auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
```

I would love to trust the documentation, but I could be misreading it. Moreover, it would be great if I knew how to 'refresh' my credentials for a user every month or so to avoid the possibility of it expiring. Can anyone either share with me how they periodically refresh a users credentials with the official [google gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) or shed some light on the documentation about this magical refresh, "The client object will refresh the access token as needed"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default [Ruby Google API client gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) does include auto-refresh.  As you mentioned, you have to have the "offline" scope specified to get a refresh token in the first place on your first auth.

- [Refresh Authorization Method](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/e13da8e05e2368421519e49d2c03ee7e69f3faaa/lib/google/api_client/auth/storage.rb#L75)
- [Test case for refreshing expired token](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/e13da8e05e2368421519e49d2c03ee7e69f3faaa/spec/google/api_client/auth/storage_spec.rb#L82)

That said, while I haven't used Signet, I have used Omniauth to manually refresh tokens before.  It goes something like this.

```
def refresh_oauth
  strategy = OmniAuth::Strategies::GoogleOauth2.new(
    nil,
    Rails.application.secrets.fetch(:google_client_id),
    Rails.application.secrets.fetch(:google_client_secret),
  )

  client = strategy.client

  token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(
    client,
    oauth_token,
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
  )

  token.refresh!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

credentials_path = "path_to_file/client_secrets.json"
credentials = JSON.parse(File.read(credentials_path))['web']
data = {
  :client_id => credentials['client_id'],
  :client_secret => credentials['client_secret'],
  :refresh_token => credentials['refresh_token'],
  :project_id => credentials['project_id'],
  :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
}
authorizer = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(data)
new_access_token = authorizer.fetch_access_token['access_token']
puts new_access_token
```

Reference : https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/main/lib/googleauth/user_refresh.rb